# Problem with indentation when using tabular{} function

Tags: tables, indentation

I'm trying to edit a block of text to look like this:

[image]

**But then I get the following output,**

[image]

It gets a weird indentation. I tried to use command `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` at the beginning of the document and changing justification position from `rl` for another options like `cc` or `ll`, but got the same output. Also tried to use the `\large` command outside the brackets insted of outside, but still no difference. :/

Is there anything else I can do? And why does this happens?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Here is the an example code with the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

    \textbf{\large Web access:}\href{}{}\\[\baselineskip]
    \begin{tabular}{rl} 
        \textbf{\large Key Words:}  & Nonlinear Dynamics \\
                            & Isogeometric Analysis\\
                            & Porosity-dependent properties\\
                            & Functionally graded materials\\
                            & Non-classical continuum elasticity\\
    \end{tabular}\\[\baselineskip]

    \textbf{\large General subject:}\\[\baselineskip]

\end{document}
```

Comment: please post an example that we can compile.

Comment: Try placing a `\noindent` before `\begin{tabular}` to avoid the paragraph indent.

Comment: @Mafsi I've edited one in the post.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes tried it, but still doesnt work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "Key Words" are part of the `tabular` construction itself, and are thus subject to the `\tabcolsep` margin inside the `tabular`.  That is overridden manually with a `{@{}rl}` column specification, where the `@{}` means "don't do anything before this column".

This, of course, is what David said, without providing an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

    \textbf{\large Web access:}\href{}{}\\[\baselineskip]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rl} 
        \textbf{\large Key Words:}  & Nonlinear Dynamics \\
                            & Isogeometric Analysis\\
                            & Porosity-dependent properties\\
                            & Functionally graded materials\\
                            & Non-classical continuum elasticity\\
    \end{tabular}\\[\baselineskip]
%
    \textbf{\large General subject:}\\[\baselineskip]
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Something apparently so simple can sometimes be a nightmare when someone is new at it... thats my case here :/

Comment: @JoaoSilva I figured you needed to *see* an example.  It is why posting a small example with each question is so important.

Answer (score 3):

please always post code as text not an image. Your image presumably does not match your code (no `\`  before  `textbf` for example, which makes it even harder to debug.)

Your `tabular` has a paragraph indent to its left as it starts a paragraph, that may be zero if you have set `\parindent` to 0pt. It also has `\tabcolsep` spacing to the left of the first column, which you can remove from either end of the table with with `{@{}rl@{}`

Unrelated but you must get a warning about underful hbox from the misplaced `\\`  after the tabular (never end a paragraph with `\\` ) and probably you should be using structural markup like `\section*{General Subject}`  rather than low level font commands

Comment: Ok, no probem. Thanks for the tips.